# Project does not compile after update of thinktecture.identitymodel 2.6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, thinktecture-ident-model

I have updated my project yesterday with IdentityModel 2.6, and I can't find why it does not compile anymore with this error.

```
error ASPRUNTIME : The pre-application start initialization method Start on type
Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Web.Configuration.AppStart threw an exception with the 
following error message: Value cannot be null.
```

I have just updated the package, no code change.

**EDIT:**
The problem comes from missing web.config section described here http://brockallen.com/2013/05/28/configuration-for-wif-session-helper-apis-in-thinktecture-identitymodel/

This seems mandatory and all attributes must be filled otherwise it throws...
sessionTokenCacheType for exemple must be filled...

It would be great to have more information on this.

TIA

Comment: Sometimes packages come with a Powershell script that modify parts of your project, take a look at your project Assembly.cs, or better run a `git diff` or equivalent command if you have a source control.

Comment: only packages.config and csproj updated.

Comment: So seems that they changed an API call or a configuration, take a look at `AssemblyInfo.cs` and look for `Thinktecture` usages, you may find a clue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug in 2.6. Please upgrade to 2.6.1

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug and has been fixed in 2.6.1. Update from NuGet again. Sorry for the inconvenience.